# Topology generated by complete and incomplete uniformities

Tags: examples, uniform-spaces

Does there exist a topology which can be induced simultaneously by a complete and an incomplete uniformity?

Comment: Related: [Two metrics induce the same topology, but one is complete and the other isn't](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7578)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Can you tell me any book that discusses it.

Answer (score 1):

$]0,1[$ and the real line are, famously, homeomorphic but the latter is complete whereas the former is not (both under the usual metric).

Comment: Can you tell me any book that discusses it